Derived class fields cannot be autocompleted
https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/MYGwhgzhAECCA8AVaBTAHgFxQOwCYwCUVgB7AJ13ggzIEtsBzAGmgFdsBrbEgd2wD5+0AN4AoaNGpgsAfgBc0RAG5xklBgDKGaSmgBeaAAoADmACeIEmFwKACmDIZaYEEn4BKfUOEBfUX9FQSBgAIVRMHHw4eGFoMAVsVgBbACMUMh9vVSksfREJPwkSbABhEFpgDjyMAAtaCAA6CHUtHUNYn3d-UR7RIA

class A<T extends Record<string, unknown>> {
  state?: T;
}

class B extends A<{ a: number}> {
  state = { /** cannot autocomplete */ }
}

Since TypeScript believes that the type of state is wrong, why not help me complete it automatically?

Sometimes TS does not infer the types due to limiations
I tried specifying explicit type and it worked
`class B extends A<{ a: number }> {
state: { a: number } = { a: 1 };
}
`

What is happening here is that there are actually two different state properties, one in the parent class and one in the child class. So theoretically this means that you could create the property in the child class as you want, but as its value will be used to override the one in the parent class TypeScript will need them to be of the same type.
So there is no autocompletion here because when you are creating the property in the child class, it has no direct link with the one in the parent class.
To prevent this kind of issue you can assign the value in the constructor of the child class by using this.state
class B extends A<{ a: number}> {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = { /** there is autocompletion here */ }
  }
}


Thanks. this work. Most confusing me is that TypeScript has given error Property 'a' is missing in type '{}' but required in type '{ a: number; }', but does not help me complete automatically

Glad that i helped ! I get that this can be confusing, but it actually makes sense when you know how the overriding of a member of a class works in TypeScript. A possible way to get rid of this kind of issue is to always explicitly type you properties (and that is a good practice to do that with non primitive types to make the class easier to read)
